# php apc_fetch all ids

Tags: php, caching, apc, outputcache

Is there a way to fetch and print, all the data stored in apc's storage?

I need to do so for testing and debugging purposes.

I know I can retrieve a specific data by doing `apc_fetch(id)`, but I don't know any way to retrieve all the data by passing (as an example) a `*`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can get this with [`APCIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apciterator.construct.php). This allows you to loop through all the items stored with APC.

```
$iter = new APCIterator('user');
foreach ($iter as $item) {
    echo $item['key'] . ': ' . $item['value'];
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, with this code I get the keys... which is more than enough to see what I'm caching in my app

Comment: When doing this i get " Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" also backtrace shows that the rewind() method is to blame. My regex matches exactly 1 entry in APC. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

[apc_cache_info()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php) might be what you're looking for

Comment: ok, this isn't exactly what I am looking for. This doesn't retrieve the cached data. But thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

[The APCIterator class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.apciterator.php) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

APC extension is not installed on your APache.

so download a APc based on your  PHP version and install it.

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

if you need installation tuts.  read it here.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/solution-call-undefined-function-apc_fetch/